# How does .NET optimise properties with operations?

Tags: c#, .net

For discussion, I have this class with properties

```
public class Intresting
{
   decimal _mQty, _mSpareQty;

   public Qty { get { return _mQty; } set { _mQty = value; } }
   public SpareQty { get { return _mSpareQty; } set { _mSpareQty= value; } }
   public SparePercentage
   { 
     get { return _mQty == 0 ?  0 : _mSpareQty / _mQty; }
     set { _SpareQty = Qty * value; }
   }
}
```

I am concern If I have 1,000,000 Interesting objects displayed in a custom GridView in a read only situation which shows SparePercentage via the property, the SparePercentage will be calculated over and over again or will there be optimised for example using a third _mSpareQtyPercentage which gets recalculated when Qty and SpareQty is set?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  Try it and if you see your program has trouble at this particular spot fix it.  If not, stop worrying!

Comment: I'd say the million-item gridview would be your problem, not the math. (I can't say I'm a fan of the setter on the percentage modifying another value, either.)

Comment: Simple answer is that it doesn't. But worry about this later. The first order of business is fixing that `GridView` control that contains 1,000,000 objects, whether `Interesting` or not. That's a serious usability problem. No one wants to or can handle seeing a million items at one time.

Comment: Actually, that was just an example. I have also read the "root of all evil" argument a million times now. Say if it wasn't just a simple + - * / but something along sin(), cos(), sqrt(). This question is more of curiosity than solving a problem. Thanks for you comments either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I very much doubt that there's anything in the JIT which would perform that optimization for you - after all, that requires more work each time `Qty` and `SpareQty` are set, and more space per object. That's not a trade-off the JIT should be doing for you. You could do that yourself, of course - just don't expect either the C# or JIT compiler to do it for you.

I *would* expect the JIT compiler to inline your trivial properties - which can be written as *automatically implemented properties* as of C# 3:

```
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
public decimal SpareQuantity { get; set; }
```

(Note the changes to make the names more readable at the same time, by the way.)

Comment: *thinking to myself: Is there an impulse bias towards up voting Jon Skeet?*

Comment: thanks =) I shall read up the inlining part. new info for me.

Answer (score 4):

The JIT will do nothing in particular to optimize this property and it will hence be re-evaluated in full every time it's asked for.  However I doubt this would ever show up as a source of performance problems in your application.  I certainly wouldn't go thruogh the troulbe of caching the result myself until a profile noted that as a problem in my application.

Note: It's also odd to have a property which has a get which is a calculation and has a set at all.  When there is a calculation in the getter I usually prefer to avoid a setter entirely and instead force the caller to mutate the underlying values that are a par of the calculation

Comment: I have in the past met with the requirement to implement certain interfaces which exposes similar properties. In that sense, I cannot really avoid, or can I?

Comment: @Jake in that sense no you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will perform the calculation every time it is called.  If you want to avoid that, you will have to implement your own cacheing.

.NET doesn't "optimize" properties any more than it optimizes any other functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason it is **not** recommended to put more than a getter to the backing field. If there is an operation to be performed, it should occur in a method. There is nothing in the compiler that would make an assumption about how the code should be executed.

The sample will execute the formula every time that getter is called. OT, but in a threaded environment, I would expect that the only way I could get the value would be to call a method.